# Store string in c# application which does not change after first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, c#-4.0

I have a application developed in C# and I want that the first time when user open the application it stores the key, user system mac address and system ip in a variable and whenever user again open the application I can find the first entered data which was stored. But i don't want to store it on the users system that he can edit that. Do we have any option to do it in the application it self.

Comment: short answer: no. long answer: nooooooooooooooooooo. also: there is _no_ 100% tamper-proof client identifier.

Comment: So you're looking for _persistent data_. There's a lot of ways to do that, from text files, registry values, databases, and so on. Have you tried anything yet? What are your requirements?

Comment: Well if you don't want to store it on the users system, that suggests the idea that you need to story it on some other system. Generally such a system would be called a server. Have you looked into setting up a server to receive and store this information for you? Of course you'll have to be satisfied with the idea that users can generally manipulate anything on their own system, including data coming from servers. Just how secure do you need this to be?

Comment: @fra There's [SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.getsystemidforpublisher) that returns a unique user ID. This ID is *"persistent across restarts, reinstalls and upgrades of Windows, including clean installs"* and *"across most hardware modifications"*.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this link of [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.usemachinekeystore?view=netcore-3.1) you could use the `System.Security.Cryptography` to store your secrets. For example:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        // Set the static UseMachineKeyStore property to use the machine key
        // store instead of the user profile key store.
        RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
        try
        {

            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            //Name the container where the key are going to be stored. I sugest use the MAC address as a container name
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "MyContainer";

            byte[] infoToStore;
            
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
            {
                //Store the key in the provider
                RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
                //Encrypt the data you need to save
                infoToStore = RSAalg.EncryptValue(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MAC:ADDRESS.....IP.ADRESS...... all info"));
            }
            //Save the data to a file, a BD or a Registry
            SaveToFile(infoToStore);

            byte[] decryted;
            //To decrypt the data
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
            {
               //Read the dat from file, Registry, etc.
                byte[] info = ReadFromFile();
                decryted = RSAalg.DecryptValue(info);
            }
            //Process de decrypted data as you needed
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryted));
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```